# can't call method prepare on an undefined value perl

Tags: perl

In dbutils.pm file we are using

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($checkUser) or return ($::FALSE,"checkUser prepare failed ");
```

in this statement getting error like **can't call method prepare on an undefined value**   same statement using in this file for many times but I didn't get any error like this.
prepare($checkUser) --> checkUser is SQL query and its returning something. there is no issue with query its returning values.

We are using `sub dbLogin { }` function. In this function we have given:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:Or‌​acle:DBname', 'username', 'pwd')
  or die "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;
```

And this function is returning `$dbh` so as per your suggestion we already using that `$dbh` code of line.

What ever the $dbh is returning that we are using in many times & places in dbUtil.pm file.

Please suggest me to resolve this issue.

Comment: None of the details that you have added have altered the situation at all. The problem is that `$dbh` is undefined  when you use it to call `prepare()`. You need to work out why it isn't set at that point in your program.

Comment: we are calling sub dbLogin() function for everytime while calling prepare()
like 
my $dbh= &dbLogin;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($checkUser) or return ($::FALSE,"checkUser prepare failed ");.

Comment: Then `dbLogin()` is returning an undefined value for some reason. You'll need to work out why that is. And, please don't call subroutines with `&`. It's potentially confusing and hasn't been required for over twenty years.

Comment: how come it is giving undefined value i am not getting..because we have 2k lines of code and in that file same my $dbh=&dbLogin(); is used for so many times...here we are getting issue when we are calling $dbh->prepare() for the last lines of code.

Comment: I have no idea. That's for you to find out. If I was debugging this I'd be printing the value of `$dbh` in three places - as it's returned from `connect()`, just before it's returned from `dbLogin()` and just before it's used to call `prepare()`. That will show you where it first gets undefined. But if you're a programmer, you should be able to work this out for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It means `$dbh` is not correct. Please write your `$dbh` like below and see if it's failing to make connection.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $auth, \%attr)
                or die "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;
```

Alternatively

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $auth, { RaiseError => 1 });
```

---

As per your edited question:

Print dumper of `$dbh` after calling the `dbLogin` subroutine (just before `prepare` statement) to see if it is undefined. If that's the case then you need to debug further to see what is modifying `$dbh`.

Comment: Hi Chankey, here we are using sub dbLogin  { } function.in this function we have given $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:Oracle:DBname', 'username', 'pwd') or die "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr; like this and this function is returning $dbh; so as per your suggestion we already using that $dbh code of line.

Comment: If your `dbLogin()` function is returning a valid `$dbh`, but `$dbh` is undefined by the time you use it to call `prepare()`, then something must be overwriting the value. Or perhaps you're not using the correct `$dbh` variable. Do you have `my $dbh` somewhere that is masking the original variable?

Comment: If you have largish code fragments (like the `dbLogin()` function, it would be helpful if you could edit your question to include them instead of putting them in comments where they are very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so let's look at that error.

> can't call method prepare on an undefined value

Perl tells you that you're calling the method `prepare()` on an undefined value. What does that mean?

In your code you have this line:

`my $sth = $dbh->prepare(...);`

Here, `prepare()` is a method which you are calling on the object `$dbh`. If Perl is telling you that you're calling it on an undefined value, then at this point of your code `$dbh` must be undefined.

So you need to look at where you think that `$dbh` is given a value. That code is going wrong somehow. You need to add more error checking around there in order to find out what is going wrong. The code that [Chankey suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38968199/7231) looks like an excellent start.